# Laravel Error #68:Frame not found in cellmap

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I'm trying to create code to export PDF file ,And this statement to do that (at Controller.php):

```
$pdf=PDF::loadView('backend.diennuoc.diennuoc-pdf',$data);
return $pdf->download('Hoadondiennuoc.pdf');
```

it has a error :

```
Dompdf \ Exception
Frame not found in cellmap
```

I don't know how to fix this error. Give me explanation, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the below code :

```
$pdf=PDF::loadView('backend.diennuoc.diennuoc-pdf',$data)->setPaper('a4');
return $pdf->download('Hoadondiennuoc.pdf');
```

Note: `setPaper()` is optional and it accepts 2 parameters i.e 1st is paper size 2nd is orientation of page.

E.g : `setPaper('a4', 'landscape')`

Comment: I edited as your code but it was still error "Frame not found in cellmap". Do you have another solution? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I knew that this error happened from. For anyone gets this circumstance as me,
That's error about "format page" when creating source code to pdf file.
Like : you create html tags: `<table>` or `<td>` or `<th>` is wrong . Therefore, you will check these correctly.